# React JS array filter returns empty array although filter returns true

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
let destUpdate = this.state.destinations.filter((dest) => {
    return !toRemove.includes(dest);
})
```

This is the code I have. Usually, it works as I want but I have a specific example where it does a weird thing.

In the example, `this.state.destinations` contain contains only one element, and `toRemove` is an empty array.

Since toRemove is empty, the filter will return true and should add dest to the new array but the returned array from filter `(destUpdate)` is empty.
How can this be?
Also, if I write the code like this:

```
let destUpdate = [];
this.state.destinations.forEach((dest) => {
    if (!toRemove.includes(dest))
        destUpdate.push(dest);
});
```

destUpdate is still empty (In the example where `toRemove` is empty and `this.state.destinations` contains contains only one element)

update:

```
toRemove: []

this.state.destinations: [{"lat":51.4862408,"lng":-0.1601986,"name":"National Army Museum","place_id":"ChIJma2VQBEFdkgRfxsd5E7cC3c","open":null,"timeSpent":1,"types":["tourist_attraction","museum","point_of_interest","establishment"],"assignedTime":"14:00 Friday","date":"10/4/2020"}]
```

Also, this code prints a non-empty array(as I want):

```
 console.log(this.state.destinations.filter((dest) => {
            return !toRemove.includes(dest);
        }))
```

Comment: What do your `state.destinations` and `toRemove` arrays look like? Please provide the exact values if possible.

Comment: I updated the question with the arrays looks

Comment: This should be working... Are you retrieving the destinations via API request on page load/component mount, that could be having issues/slower than normal? Maybe the destinations array is actually empty when it reaches your code. It may help to see more of your component in question.

Comment: It is not retrieved via API and it is not empty as well.
I checked everything(printed state.destinations before filter and after and so on)